# How to greyout a card in a card view?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-cardview

I have a card view that lists a set of cards dynamically. I have used recyclerview for that. Now I want to disable a card(based on value)by greying out the card or something like that. This is the layout that contains the card view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="112dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/appIcon"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="62dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/appIcon"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                android:textColor="@drawable/selector"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/appVersion"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
                android:text="version 0.0"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                android:textSize="8dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have found some related queries and have tried out using selectors and greying out each field instead of the entire card.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:color="@color/colorAppName" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />

</selector>
```

**and in my class(Adapter.kt)**

```
name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name) as TextView
if(value==true)
{
  name.isEnabled=false
}
```

But I want to disable the entire card. Please help

Comment: take id of cardview and apply enable false on it.

Comment: @HemantParmar I tried that but still couldn't see any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set tint to your relative layout which is direct child of card view in your item design. You have to do this in xml:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="112dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relParent"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:padding="8dp">
      ....>
```

I have added two property in RelativeLayout first is id and second is background.

Now in adapter you can do this:

```
if(value==true)  
{
itemView.relParent.background.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#6F6F6F"),PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
        itemView.relParent.isEnabled=false
}
else
{
itemView.relParent.background.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"),PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
        itemView.relParent.isEnabled=true
}
```

**Note:** You must have to set background to RelativeLayout from xml otherwise itemView.relParent.background will return null and your app will crash.

**Update**
You need to set forground color to your card you in that case do this:

```
itemView.cardDashboard.foreground= ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#906F6F6F"))
```

Here cardDashboard is card view which you are using in your item design.

So the final code will be like this:

```
       if(value==true)  
        {
        itemView.cardDashboard.foreground= ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#906F6F6F"))     
   itemView.relParent.isEnabled=false
        }
        else
        {
        itemView.cardDashboard.foreground= ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#006F6F6F"))
                itemView.relParent.isEnabled=true
        }
```

Comment: What is "linParent" refer to here?

Comment: Oh, Sorry i didn't changed that you have to use relParent instead of linParent, i forgot to change that, now i have updated my answer too

Comment: that's fine. I got it. This works, but even though the cards color is changed the contents(like image and text) are still highlighted. I want it to look like its disabled.

Comment: Means that you want to change the color of textview also?

Comment: Yes and also the image. So do I have to take each field and do like this?

Comment: disabling the layout might not disable its child views as well, try my answer below to diable entire card together

Comment: @AmruthaJRaj i have updated my answer please have a look

Comment: @AmruthaJRaj now it will definitely work according to your expectation.

Comment: Yeah it works better now, but yet the text and image is not yet faded. Probably I'll try with some other colors. anyways thanks

Comment: Okay, try with other colors or use forground  color to image or textview.

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:background="@drawable/selector"` to your `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`. That will work for enable and disable.

**Note:- This is not related to question but if you follow. It will good for you.**

> We compare `if(booleanVariable)` directly instead of comparison like
>   `if(booleanVariable==true)`.

Comment: Thanks, yeah i know that. actually "value" that i used is kind of big expression so in short I used value for the sake of readability.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the following to all the views,

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```

**When this attribute is set to true, the view gets its drawable state (focused, pressed, etc.) from its direct parent rather than from itself.**

Then dynamically disable the layout of the item (at a particular position) resulting in disabling all its child views.

**Note:** Since your cardviews are in a recycler view you need to maintain the state for diffrent positions inside your adapter.

You can maintain the background states using the selectors as you did before.

I changed your layouts by adding the above mentioned attribute:-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="112dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"

    android:id="@+id/cd"
    android:scaleType="fitXY">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/appIcon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"

            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appIcon"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="clickMe"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"

            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/appVersion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:text="version 0.0"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And have tested with disabling the cardview state, its child views also show the change with their color fading to light grey(haven't used selector for views so  it changes to default disabled state (tested for textview)) .But for any clicklistner on the views you will have to use the saved state for the position disabled and not perform task when state is disabled.

Comment: I tried but I see no difference in card, can you please mention like how we give this in selector to make sure I did correctly.

Comment: have tested with your layout, and updated the answer if you still are searching , you can try it once.

Comment: Word of caution with this property. You need to be careful, when child view has ripple effect set. If you for example click on parent, it will also trigger child's view ripple effect.